# Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices - fedora 37

Tags: kvm-virtualization, fedora, qemu, asus

I added the section in the xml file of the VM win10 and I got the following error:
Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices
when trying to start the VM I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1362, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices
```

I posted in this post because when I do the virt-host-validate command I got the same error the one mentioned earlier
[Ubuntu 22 No ACPI DMAR table found, IOMMU either disabled in BIOS or not supported by this hardware platform on nested VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/1119402/ubuntu-22-no-acpi-dmar-table-found-iommu-either-disabled-in-bios-or-not-support/1119759#1119759)

VT-D is enabled as we can see in the mesag

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU
[    0.076108] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    4.063133] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
```

Hardware as below

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 4-5) (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] (rev cf)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
```

I specified the PCI id in the conf as well. the hardware is old for sure but I was really hopping to use pass through feature to connect the Video adapter.

Is there any chance to get that working one day or should I look for a new hardware?

Please check the screenshots as well
[image: Virthost validate command result]
[[image: error when the VM start][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QU1K.jpg)
[[image: Domain XML file][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sl6I.jpg)

Comment: I tried  that as well https://github.com/dzintars/infra/issues/28
checked the documentation https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/VT-d
@vidarlo thanks for reformatting